# Where to store the AES encryption key in Angular?

Tags: angular, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I am using Angular 8 for UI and Java Spring Boot in backend. I have a login page in UI and want to encrypt the user typed password to a encrypted one with AES and the send it to backend using REST API and then want to decrypt that encrypted password in Java Spring Boot.

I know we can use Crypto JS as I am seeing many examples but everywhere I can see they are just giving a sample key (string) mentioning in the typescript/ javascript file. But in real life example I can't mention the key in the typescript/javascript file right?

Where to store the AES encryption 'key' in Angular?

And is it a same key for all password encryption for all the users?

Comment: You can store key in server api, and in angular side when you want to encrypt password, first you need to get key from server and then encrypt password and send back to server.

Comment: So you mean to say I can't store the key in Angular code, I have to get the key from the API? If this is the case then user will able to see the key in API Response which is a huge problem right?

Comment: One way is you can use public api key in angular to encrypt from client side, and in server you can use private key to dectypt it. This is called assymentric cyptography

Comment: So there is no way to use AES encryption with only private key? can I hide the API response / network call from user while getting the private key from API so that they can't see it?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/aes-encryptiondecryption-with-angular-7/ generally, https with ssl will do job for you from client side, all you need is authenticate user at server side. and return token if authenticated.

Comment: What's wrong with using https?